# В chrome блок автозаполнения выходит за пределы браузера

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, autocomplete

Разрабатываем сайт и у нас есть странный тестер, который вот такое называет багом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ответил, что это окно хрома, на которое повлиять невозможно, но вот прошло время и опять тот же тестер с тем же "багом"...

Стало интересно, облазил интернет и вообще не нашел упоминаний о таком блоке. В фаерфоксе такого нет, там подсказки похоже вылазят только те, что меньше ширины инпута.
Может я все-таки чего-то не знаю и этим блоком автозаполнения как-то можно управлять?

P.S.: про то, что подсказку можно отключить я знаю. Интересует именно ширина подсказки.

Comment: Гнать надо таких тестировщиков)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это и баг, то Chrome. Всегда можно отрепортить разработчикам на https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

С первого взгляда похожего случая я там не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

У тега `<input>` атрибут **autocomplete** отвечает за автозаполнение форм. Эту функциональность можно отключить в пользовательских настройках браузера или веб-мастером вручную, указав значение `"off"`.

```html
<p>В этом поле автозаполнение может быть активировано
<input name="qwe" autocomplete="on">

<p>А в этом оно принудительно отключено
<input name="qqq" autocomplete="off">
```

Стоит отметить, что для работы этого свойства требуется указание имени у поля ввода.

Comment: спасибо, видимо вопрос до конца не дочитали: еще раз: про то, что подсказку можно отключить я знаю. Интересует именно ширина подсказки.

Comment: ааа... ну у меня не времени читать всё подряд :( надо было как-то выделить ключевой вопрос